# Linq to Sql, System.Exception cast is not valid

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to map a class from SQL to a linq collection, But I fail..

I have got this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace SportsStore.Entities
{
    [Table(Name = "Products")]
    public class Product 
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Column]public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column]public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column]public `int` Price { get; set; } 
        [Column]public string Category { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I call that class from another class:

```
using SportsStore.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Entities;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;

    namespace SportsStore.Concrete
    {
        public class SqlProductsRepository : IProductRepository
        {
            private Table<Product> productsTable;

            public SqlProductsRepository(string connnectionString)
            {
                productsTable = (new DataContext(connnectionString)).GetTable<Product>();
            }

            public IQueryable<Product> Products
            {
                get { return productsTable; }
            }
        }

    }
```

Basically, I get this:

> base {System.SystemException} = {"Specified cast is not valid."}

This implies the cast is invalid

**update**
My database looks like that:

>

```
 **ProductID  int (primary key) Name  
     nvarchar(100) Description  
 nvarchar(500) Category  
 nvarchar(50) Price  int**
```

StackTrace:

> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal() +274
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i) +44
>   Read_Product(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +1088
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +406
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>
>   SportsStore.Controllers.ProductController.List() in
>   D:\Call.of.Duty.Modern.Warfare.3-RELOADED\SportsStore\SportsStore\SportsStore\Controllers\ProductController.cs:28
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +51
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +409
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
>   +127    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_c()
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +305
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +830
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +111    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_4() +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +52    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8966925    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: What is the type of `productsTable`, and what's the detail of the exception (full stack trace etc)?

Comment: I convert the returned productsTable into a list..using toList.. later on

Comment: When I step into the code  productsTable  doesnt show any results returned..it gives me the exception in place of the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error message states that the value for the `Price` column cannot be converted to a `decimal`.

You need to make sure that your database table has the correct column type for the `Price` column and that it contains valid data.

Also, if your column in the database allows NULL values, you need to map it to a nullable decimal with `decimal? Price { get; set; }`

Comment: I changed the column type to int and the product class to int too.. still I get that exception with teh same message

Comment: But now with a GetInt() instead of GetDecimal() error? Is the column nullable?

Comment: it gives me teh same exception cause, I have a problem with visual studio modifying/saving my new changes..I am working on that

Answer (score 3):

You've got a column defined as `[Column]public decimal Price { get; set; }`. Are you sure this is actually a suitable datatype for the data in the database? - could the data in the database be `Varchar`, or allow nulls?

Comment: I changed it again: decimal(16, 2) and the property   [Column]public decimal Price { get; set; }    .... should be right

Comment: I think I know where the problem is...I have to go to the configurations and allow database saving